# Updating a single value in a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I'm trying to update a value in an existing row of a database but I can't seem to get the changes to stick. the code in my controller currently looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCredit(int employeeNumber, decimal amount)
        {
            var employee = new GetEmployeeForEmployeeNumber<Employee>(employeeNumber).Query().FirstOrDefault();

            var employeeAccount = new GetEmployeeAccountForId<EmployeeAccount>(employee.Id).Query().FirstOrDefault();

            employeeAccount.Credit = employeeAccount.Credit + amount;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Home", new { employeeNumber });
        }
```

Based on research that I've done into the subject, this should work as I've modelled it off working example. The Credit does increase by the given amount but after the db.SaveChanges, the values in the database are still as they were. 
Am I missing something obvious?

Edit:

The GetEmployeeAccountForId looks like this:

```
public class GetEmployeeAccountForId<T>
        {
            private TestContext db = new TestContext();

            private readonly int _id;

            public GetEmployeeAccountForId(int id)
            {
                _id = id;
            }

            public IQueryable<EmployeeAccount> Query()
            {
                return from employeeAcount in db.EmployeeAccounts
                       where employeeAcount.Id == _id
                       select employeeAcount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the method content behind `GetEmployeeAccountForId<T>()` and `Query()`? Include them to help us find out why update to DB is not executing.

Comment: I've updated the question to include that

Comment: What version of entity framework You are using?

Comment: I think the problem originates from different context references used, since `GetEmployeeAccountForId<T>` uses internal context to query the DB, and you're calling `db.SaveChanges` at the controller level. To perform update on different contexts, you need to attach or set it to modified state before calling `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
employeeAccount.Credit = employeeAccount.Credit + amount;
db.Entry(employeeAccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Update**
You have to "tell" EF to track changes of editet entity, that's why

```
db.Entry(employeeAccount).State = EntityState.Modified
```

is required.
But You also shoudn't use 2 different instances of one DbContext. I highly recomend using DI, and set DbContext life time to instance per request.

Comment: I've tried db.Update but it doesn't exist. Is it part an extension?

Comment: I've updated answer. db.Update is in EF core. Use older version:

    db.Entry(employeeAccount).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: It should work, but You shouldn't use 2 instances of DbContext. I highly recomend using DI and set DbContext scope to instance per request